# SWT- Group taking entire space and hiding other Group during window maximize

Tags: java, swt

I have a composite where three groups are already existing such that two groups at left and one group on right. When I added new group to right side this and tried to maximize the window then newly added group disappeared and previously existing group taking all space. How to solve this?

something like this where Group1 already exsists and Group2 is added newly:-

```
Group1= new Group(compositename, SWT.NONE);
Group1.setLayOutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true ));

Group2= new Group(compositename, SWT.NONE);
Group2.setLayOutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true ));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a snippet that makes your problem reproducable?

Comment: As a note: Please stick to Java [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Answer (score 0):

(sorry I don't have the rep to make this a comment) But, duplicate question by the same user, see my answer in the newest thread, I think it'll help you solve some of your trouble with this: 
[SWT-How to restrict Text from taking Vertically all space and hide other controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629261/swt-how-to-restrict-text-from-taking-vertically-all-space-and-hide-other-control/19707751#19707751)