# SWT-How to restrict Text from taking Vertically all space and hide other controls

Tags: java, swt

I have a SWT text and it have large contents. Because of its contents when I maximize window textbox will grow vertically and hides remaining controls.

```
Text contentText=new Text( GroupName, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.WRAP );

contentText.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1 ) );
```

How to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't hide anything if you are using the `GridLayout` correctly. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) so we can see how you are creating/using the layout?

Comment: Something like this.

Group  grp=new Group(CompositeName,SWT.NONE);
grp.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, true ) );
            grp.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true ) );
Text contentText=new Text( GroupName, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.WRAP );

contentText.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1 ) );

Comment: I don't see any problem with that code and can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends entirely upon how you are placing the contentText within the layout itself. For example, if you are using a `GridLayout` (just one) and it's a say, a 1 X 2 grid (or n X 2 really since you only need to control how many columns are in a given row for grid layouts), and you place the contentText object within the 'right' grid, and instantiate the contentText like you did with a gridData as such:

```
    contentText.setlayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1,1));
```

Lets take a look at what exactly is happening with all of those parameters. From the : [swt api on GridData](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html), you are using this constructor:

```
    GridData(int horizontalAlignment, int verticalAlignment, boolean grabExcessHorizontalSpace, boolean grabExcessVerticalSpace, int horizontalSpan, int verticalSpan)
```

Alrright, so what this tells me is that we want our contentText to use the SWT.FILL parameters for both the horizontal and veritcal alignments (makes it so that objects are spaced equally horizontally and vertically, I believe). you DO want it to grab as much excessive horizontal and vertical space as it possibly can, and you want it to span one grid element in both the horizontal and vertical direction. Now, although this by itself won't override and cover up all the rest of the controls on the screen statically, but when you resize, you're still telling the contentText to take up as much vertical space as it can (it's limited horizontally by other object within the same composite/grid Layout I imagine, which is why you're not seeing any override there).

Now, this could be caused by how you have the overall composite/form structured, and which objects are contained in which composites, etc. etc. A small factor will throw things off a lot. However, learning how to use the various layout data constructors to work FOR you instead of against you, is a huge benefit in SWT. I would take a look [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) to understand layouts more thoroughly, and really just pay attention to every single parameter in these constructors you're making. Many times you don't need the full 6-parameter constructor, and there are other options.

Good luck!